Error "The projectSettings object is required for new projects, but is missing in the deployment payload"
I am trying to deploy a FastAPI app as a serverless function on vercel, using vercel CLI. Deployment successfully occurs.
When I'm trying to promote deployment to production a message pops up saying " The projectSettings object is required for new projects, but is missing in the deployment payload" .
No any documentation about such error is marked anywhere. Any workarounds?
Screenshot of the issue on vercel:

When using "promote to production" button on vercel app's deployment, it says "The projectSettings object is required for new projects, but is missing in the deployment payload".

This is indeed a Vercel unexpected issue. I will alert the team.

Try this command : vercel --prod

Thanks for your answer. That way works. But I want to do is to do a preview deployment and then promote it to deployment.
